# Why axios.get doesn't work when I use redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm creating a page with pictures from json file. It works untill I add redux. I'm a total newbie in redus so I hope you can help me to find my mistake. Thank you.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getCards } from "../cardsActions";
import PortfolioItem from "../Pages/PortfolioItem";

export default function Portfolio() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cardsListData = useSelector((state) => state.cardsList);
  const { loading, error, cards } = cardsListData;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCards());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="portfolio-wrapper">
        {loading
          ? "Loading..."
          : error
          ? error.message
          : cards.map((card) => <PortfolioItem key={card.id} {...card} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

cardReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  cards: [],
  loading: true
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CARDS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case CARDS_ERROR:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is the full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-mcclintock-di9bb?file=/src/cardsActions.js

Comment: Where is the axios logic? Is that wrapped up in an asynchronous action? Your codesandbox is missing a few files and doesn't run. Is your server running on `http://localhost:3003`? Are you seeing an error when fetching? Can you better describe what exactly isn't working with redux?

Comment: @DrewReese I just added the full code in codesandbox.

Comment: I am getting this error `Could not find module in path: '../Pages/PortfolioItem' relative to '/src/Pages/Portfolio.js'` in the codesandbox. Your issue is not reproducible.

Comment: There is an issue in `Portfolio` about how the component gets imported (wrong path). I will agree that the issue not reproduceable as there is lack of `react-boostrap` dependency in `package.json` as well. @daryalewy If you really want to get assistance, please review your code and update the post.

Comment: @yudhiesh I fulfilled code and added all I have.
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-mcclintock-di9bb?file=/src/cardsActions.js

Comment: @Reborn thank you for your comment. I added everything I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you added your cards to the wrong key in your redux store:

```
case GET_CARDS:
  return {
    ...state,
    users: action.payload, // <-- users isn't accessed in UI
    loading: false
  };
```

You access `state.cardsList.cards` though. Save the payload to the `cards` part of your state.

```
case GET_CARDS:
  return {
    ...state,
    cards: action.payload, // <-- save payload to cards state
    loading: false
  };
```

I had to mock a JSON API endpoint, but simply swapping that out allowed me to continue tracing through your code. Barring any issues with your specific local server setup (i.e. assuming your server correctly serves up the `portfolio-data.json` file) this should resolve at least your updating state and UI issue.